# how to host a web app on a linux box but still use windows authentication?

Tags: linux, webserver, node.js, windows-authentication

What do you need to have a web app hosted on a linux that uses windows authentication?

I mean we have a lot of applications in our intranet on IIS servers. These applications almost always rely on windows authentication.

We are thinking of putting up a node-based web application. And we know how to set that up too. But we're not sure stuff we've to do in order to make it windows integrated...

What solution is there to host a web app on a linux vm (which is in the same network as those other machines) but still use windows authentication as an authentication mechanism?

Comment: http://ldapjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

For a node based application, the following npm package does the trick...well, somewhat...

https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm

This requires the linux box is in the same network as the AD.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.